# SAS: Report Function trouble

Tags: dataset, report, sas

I want to rewrite code for dataset in report proc.

1) Dataset `One` with fields (`name_id` `test_var`)

2) `test_var` can be positive, negative, zero.

3) as result, i want table like this:

name_chr test_var_pos test_var_neg test_var_zero

/*data here, grouping by name_chr */

TOTAL:    SUM_POS       SUM_NEG      SUM_ZERO   <- after all rows i want this TOTAL

4)additional: i have dictionary for name_id => name_chr

5)P.S: name_id contains dots!!!!(and i want them in a result table)

6)

```
data result(keep=name_chr test_var_pos test_var_neg test_var_zero);
  retain name_chr "";
  retain test_var_pos  0;
  retain test_var_neg  0;
  retain test_var_zero 0;
  set One;
  by name_id;  /*already sorted by name_id*/
  if(FIRST.name_id) then do;
    name_chr="";
    test_var_pos = 0;
    test_var_neg = 0;
    test_var_zero = 0;
  end;
  else do;
    if(test_var>0) then test_var_pos=test_var_pos + test_var;
    if(test_var<0) then test_var_neg=test_var_neg + abs(test_var);
    if(test_var=0) then test_var_zero=test_var_zero + 1; /*as example, test_var_zero is    a count*/

  end;
 if (LAST.name_id) then do; 
      %mFIND(name_id,name_chr);
      output;
 end;
 run;
```

I want to rewrite this code in proc report and add `TOTAL` line to this dataset.

So, what i do:

1) name_id must be group value in the end.

2) i must compute all positive, negative and zero - values of test_var.

```
 proc report data = One out = Result_table(keep= name_chr test_var_pos test_var_neg test_var_zero); 
 column name_id name_chr test_var test_var_pos test_var_neg test_var_zero;
 /*from One - table*/
 define name_id /group;
 define test_var / computed;
 /*to Result_table*/
 define name_chr / computed;
 define test_var_pos / computed;
 define test_var_neg / computed;
 define test_var_zero / computed;

 compute before name_id;  /*is this eq to FIRST?*/
    name_chr="";
    test_var_pos = 0;
    test_var_neg = 0;
    test_var_zero = 0;
 endcomp;
 compute test_var_pos;
    if(test_var>0) then test_var_pos = test_var_pos + test_var;
 endcomp;
 compute test_var_neg;
    if(test_var<0) then test_var_neg = test_var_neg + abs(test_var);
 endcomp;
 compute test_var_zero;
    if(test_var=0) then test_var_zero = test_var_zero + 1;
 endcomp;
 compute after name_id; /*is it eq to LAST?*/
    /*magic to get name_chr*/
    %mFIND(name_id,name_chr);
    /*output*/
 endcomp;
 rbreak after / summarize;
 compute after rbreak; 
   name_chr = "TOTAL: ";
 encomp;
 run;
```

Comment: Tell us what your goal is...rather than "how do I fix this" and there are good programmers here who will offer good solutions

Comment: @CarolinaJay65 i think about `proc report` to do job, that proc report shouldn't do. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total line for presentation (CarolinaJay is right here) only,  then you can massage the data so that `proc report` will create your totals for you.

With out any example dataset, I'm going to make the assumption that a name_id can be in your dataset multiple times with different `test_vars`.

Knowing that your going to use `proc report` to do the summaries, I'd probably do something like the following:

```
data prepped;
 set one;
 if test_var > 0 then test_var_pos = 1;
 else if test_var = 0 then test_var_zero = 1;
 else if test_var < 0 then test_var_neg = 1;
run;
```

You'd want to order the if / else if statements in order of the most occurring to possibly squeeze out some efficiency if you're dealing with a very large dataset.

From there, it's a matter of `proc freq`, `proc summary`, `proc report`, proc whatever will do want you want which is to condense the counts.

For a summary by `name_id` and then an overall summary, you *could* use proc report.  Again, it may not be the *best* option depending on your dataset and your computing power.

Same logic as my previous answer using proc report:

```
proc report data = prepped out=summary nowd;
 col name_id test_var_pos test_var_zero test_var_positive;
 define name_id / group;
 rbreak after / summarize;
run;
```

Again,  any of the other procs could get you the summaries by group, and then you could feed that data set into `proc report` to get that summary line on the bottom. Just exclude the `/group` on the name_id.

Getting comfortable with how the underlying data needs to be structured for each of the SAS procedures will go a LONG LONG LONG way in harnessing the power of the built in procs.

Comment: so, i must make summarize by name_id and then with `proc report` add total line? hmmm good:)

Comment: Could you do it all with proc report?  Sure,  but.....it's not nessecarily the *best* tool to do all of your processing.  Depending on the size of the dataset it may make sense to make `prepped` a view so that the data only gets loaded into the memory once.

Answer (score 1):

Proc report does not process a data set...it presents it. It can be in HTML, PDF, RTF, etc. The typical workflow is to prepare your data with a data step or a procedure. Then present your data with a report procedure (like Proc Report).